# Creating new matrix from existing matrix by specifying rows/columns

Tags: python, numpy

In NumPy, suppose I have a square, matrix `X`:

```
X = array([[3, 1, 4, 5], [5, 1, 2, 1], [4, 4, 0, 1], [0, 3, 0, 3]])
```

I now want to select a certain set of the rows/columns of this matrix, and create a new matrix `Y`. The indices of these rows/columns are stored in a list `z`.

So in this example, suppose that my indices are:

```
z = [0, 2]
```

Then my new matrix will take the `0th` and `2nd` rows/columns from `X`:

```
Y = array([[3, 4], [4, 0]])
```

My question is: Is there a simple way to do this in just one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using indexing and slicing:

```
>>> X[z][:,z]
array([[3, 4],
       [4, 0]])
```